# How to resample vector values in R?

Tags: r

I have two vectors:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
y <- c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

now i want to resample n times to such that the numbers of the two vectors can shuffle randomly and maintain their dimension. 
Eg.

at n = 1

```
x <- c(2, 4, 7, 1)
y <- c(3, 9, 8, 6, 5, 10)
```

at n = 2

```
x <- c(5, 6, 10, 3)
y <- c(1, 9, 8, 4, 2, 7)
```

how can i accomplish this in R?

Comment: Why bother with two vectors? Just shuffle one vector of length 10, and treat the first 4 as "x" and the last 6 as "y".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define your own helper function like

```
resample <- function(x,y) {
    xx <- sample(c(x,y))
    list(x=xx[1:length(x)], y=xx[-(1:length(x))])
}
```

and then use it with

```
# set.seed(15)
r1 <- resample(x,y)
r1$x
# [1] 7 2 8 5
r1$y
# [1]  3 10  4  1  9  6
r2 <- resample(x,y)
r2$x
# [1] 2 6 5 8
r2$y
# [1]  9  7 10  3  1  4
```

But it seems like you might be permuting case/control labels or something? In that case, you might have a vector of group assignments

```
group <- rep(c("x","y"), c(length(x),length(y)))
```

and then you could just sample() that each time to mix up groups

```
# set.seed(15)
(g1<-sample(group))
# [1] "y" "x" "y" "y" "x" "y" "x" "x" "y" "y"
(g2<-sample(group))
# [1] "x" "y" "y" "y" "y" "y" "y" "x" "x" "x"
```

and you could extract indexes with

```
which(g1=="x")
# [1] 2 5 7 8
which(g1=="y")
# [1]  1  3  4  6  9 10
```

if you really needed to.

Comment: g1 and g2 are same in this case? can i use both

Comment: `g1` and `g2` are different. They each represent one particular permutation of the labels. I just extracted the indexes for the first in this example.

Comment: Can i duplicates without maintaining the sequence i.e x <- c(2, 4, 6, 9), y <- c(3, 2, 8, 10, 1, 7). Note that 2 is a duplicate? Can this be achieved?